# Including JS variables in CSS Nodejs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a JSON file which will bring the style details .i.e. hexadecimal values of various buttons, font-size etc.

Developing the application in ReactJs.

And I want to use those style values in a custom class in React-Bootstrap.
But to define a custom class, a css file is needed.

Question: Any way to define a variable in CSS file which brings the values from JSON?

Comment: I think you can do that by doing changes on `document.styleSheets`. But I didn't try it so I didn't wrote that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any way to define a variable in CSS file which brings the values from JSON?
No, this is not possible with css3. 
I haven't worked with react but can't you pass your styles object to component?
If this is not the case why not to use inline style, I don't think performance hit of inline style is that relevant these days.
As a last option you could generate temp file from json and dynamically add it to page.